# Relationship between maps and maps of rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I take this exercise from Ravi Vakil's book.

Consider the map of complex manifolds sending $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ via $x \mapsto y=x^2$. We interpret $\mathbb{C}$ as the $x$-line and $\mathbb{C}$ as the $y$-line. In what sense can I picture it as the projection of the parabola $y=x^2$ in the $xy$-plane to the $y$-axis? How can I interpret the corresponding map of rings?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C[x,y]/(y-x^2)$ be the parabola, and let $\textrm{Spec }\mathbb C[y]$ be the $y$-axis . The homomorphism $$\mathbb C[y]\to\mathbb C[x,y]/(y-x^2)\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,y\mapsto x^2$$
corresponds to the projection $(a,b)\mapsto b$, where $(a,b)=(a,a^2)\in X$.

Comment: Minor quibble: your map of Specs is going in the wrong direction. Also, it might be a bit confusing to use the letters $x$ and $y$ in two different ways (both as variables and as elements of ${\bf C}$).

Comment: I stupidly copied and pasted the spectra above. Thanks!

Comment: @atricolf So my projection is on the positive part of $y$-line...

Comment: You do not have a "positive part" of the $y$-line, as we are over $\mathbb C$.